# What is the difference when comparing with parentheses: WHERE (a, b)=(1,2)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I stumbled across the follwoing (valid) query in MySQL (also works in Oracle/MSSQL when replacing `=` with `IN`):

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE (a, b)=(1,2)
```

It's the same as

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE a=1 and b=2
```

I think the definition in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html) is here:

```
simple_expr:
  [...]
  | (expr [, expr] ...)
  [...]
```

What is this called? Are there any pros and cons for using it?

Comment: Pros. Less typing. Cons. Can't use indexes I think - but I'm not certain- easy to verify though

Comment: on a first test `EXPLAIN` tells me that the same indexes are used in both queries, seems like there is no difference here

Comment: I think the first syntax is less clear if the where clause is more complex

Comment: ANSI SQL Feature 641, "Row and table constructors". (According to http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml)

Comment: It's tagged MySQL, so not sure why you're testing in oracle

Comment: It's very useful with subqueries in form of for instance `WHERE (a,b) IN (SELECT c,d FROM T)`

Comment: @Strawberry just updated the tags as this seems not to be a mysql-only question

Comment: Thanks all. ANSI SQL Feature 641 seems to be commonly refferred to as **Row Value Constructors**. Explanation and examples: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/row-value-constructor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be very handy when needed to compare multiple columns to multiple combination of values by using `IN()` :

```
 SELECT * FROM YourTable
 WHERE (col1,col2) IN((1,2),(2,3),(4,4)...)
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE (col1 = 1 and col2 = 2) OR
      (col1 = 2 and col2 = 3) OR
      (col1 = 4 and col2 = 4) OR
      ....
```

After reviewing the execution plan of both queries, I can say that in Oracle(Using `IN()` which is basically the same), the optimizer evaluate both the same way and both are using the indexes :

Separate conditions:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM dim_remedy_tickets_cache t
where t.tt_id = '1' and t.region_name = 'one';

6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                              |     1 |   311 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
7   |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DIM_REMEDY_TICKETS_CACHE     |     1 |   311 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
8   |   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | DIM_REMEDY_TICKETS_HISTORYPK |     1 |       |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Combined conditions:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM dim_remedy_tickets_cache t
where (t.tt_id,t.region_name) in  (('1','one'))

6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                              |     1 |   311 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
7   |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DIM_REMEDY_TICKETS_CACHE     |     1 |   311 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
8   |   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | DIM_REMEDY_TICKETS_HISTORYPK |     1 |       |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

I assume all RDBMS will evaluate this queries the same.

> Row constructors are legal in other contexts. For example, the following two statements are semantically equivalent (and are handled in the same way by the optimizer):

So:

Cons - May be less readable for some people , but basically no cons.

Pros - Less code , and the combination of multiple columns comparison using `IN()` :

Comment: So this works in Oracle too (it does not work in SQL Server).

Comment: Very handy when doing `IN`, e.g. `WHERE (a, b) IN (SELECT c1,c2 FROM ...`.

Comment: @ManuelM Yea, it's working using `IN()` , I think it works in SQL-Server as well.

Comment: This is a great and very elaborated answer! not many like this here, cheers! +1 .

Comment: sadly it doesn't work if there are nulls in the right side `WHERE (a,b,c) = (1,2,null)`, neither `WHERE (a,b,c) IN (1,2,null)` (`1,2,3/null` could be query parameters)

Comment: I correct myself. It WILL work using null-safe equal to <=> comparer  `WHERE (a,b,c) <=> (1,2,null)` [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)